# Recursive function crashing

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote this recursive function to calculate the terms of the sequence:

> [image]

and to place them in a `float array` of maximum 1000 element, but this function is crashing as I run and input the `float A` and I don't see what's the problem in there.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<math.h>

  void triple_root(float B[1000],int i,float A,float b,float c){ 
      float x;
      x = 0.333*((A/(b*b))+(1/c));
      B[i] = x;

      if(fabs(x-b)<=0.00001|| i==999)
          puts(" ");
      else triple_root(B,i+1,A,x,b); 
  }

  int main(){
      float A[1000],b;
      int i;

      scanf("%f",&b);
      triple_root(A,0,b,1,1);

      for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
          printf("%f\n",A[i]);
      }
      getchar();
  }
```

P.S.: The integer `i` initial value is 0, and the two floats `b` and `c` initial value is 1.

Comment: Where is your `main`?

Comment: I just need a hint for my function that im facing a problem through

Comment: As it is, your code doesn't compile because it's lacking a `main` entry point, and that's the reason it's about to be closed. Either ask a question about the error message that occurs when you try to compile this code, without the `main` entry point, or add a `main` entry point.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit test to make sure `i` stays below 1000; your code assumes that the recursion will stop before that happens, but I see nothing to insure this.

Comment: I added that if  i=1000 in the stop condition the function stops, but that didnt do the job, any more help?

Comment: 1. We can't see that and 2. If you used the assignment operator, no, that wouldn't "do the job"...

Comment: The current edit stops for me after i==23 (if b is 1).

Answer (score 1):

Even with your latest edit, the code didn't compile for me. It's possible that you were running a broken binary. Not to worry, though! I managed to fix it.

1. Remove the `<conio.h>` include. You will rarely if ever need this non-standard header. Change `getch` to `getchar`.
2. Change `void main` to `int main`. `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Viola! http://ideone.com/zeAuP1

Comment: thanks but i didnt understand why it didnt work with my previous syntax and library i.e the conio one:/ i looked at the results and all looks good